# How to make button highlight when hovered over using a template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, controltemplate

Recently started WPF and am very new to XAML. I'm trying to make a calculator that looks similar to the IOS one. However, after I changed the `Button` to `Ellipse`, the highlighting when hovered over or clicking on stopped working, if also the highlighting issue were to be fixed, how would I go about changing the colour of it?

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonEquals" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Width="47" Height="47"
        Content="=" Foreground="White"
        BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#FFFF9500">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="#FFFF9500"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.trigger?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to the `ControlTemplate` and target the `Ellipse` by name assigning an `x:Name` and referring to it via [`TargetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.setter.targetname?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). This way, you can define other states as well.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
   <Grid>
      <Ellipse x:Name="MyEllipse" Fill="#FFFF9500"/>
      <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   </Grid>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="OrangeRed"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
      </Trigger>
      <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
         <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
      </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This targets only the `Fill` of the `Ellipse`, without changing other controls in the template. However, the values are hardcoded and not changable from outside.

If you want the template to be customizable to a certain degree, then you can put it in a `Style` and bind properties on the templated control using [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.templatebindingextension?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with [`TemplatedParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for two-way and special scenarios. Additionally, you can add a [`FocusVisualStyle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.focusvisualstyle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that allows to specify a template for keyboard focusing.

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF9500"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
      <Setter.Value>
         <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate>
                     <Ellipse StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="DarkGreen" StrokeThickness="2"/>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
               <Ellipse x:Name="MyEllipse" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="OrangeRed"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Blue"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                  <Setter TargetName="MyEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Gray"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to reuse the style on multiple buttons, add it to a resource dictionary in scope and assign an `x:Key` to refer to it via [`StaticResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.staticresourceextension?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or [`DynamicResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dynamicresourceextension?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

Comment: @IllusiVeXI_11 I have extended the answer to cover styles and focus visual, in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Style` of button instead `Template`. Button's template you can set inside style (read more about `Style` in WPF):

```
        <Button x:Name="ButtonEquals"
                Grid.Column="4"
                Grid.Row="6"
                Width="47"
                Height="47"
                Content="=">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <!-- Here is properties for buttons with same style-->
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF9500"/>
                    
                    <!-- Here is your template -->
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    
                    <!-- Here is style triggers for interact with button -->
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <!-- Set color as you wish -->
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSalmon"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

But actually, you need to create global `ResourceDictionary` (read about it) and there set styles for all buttons like `<Style x:Key="CalculatorButton">` for set to buttons like `<Button Content="1" Style="{StaticResource CalculatorButton}"/>`